# Matplotlib crashes Python on Windows 10

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda

I installed Anaconda on my Windows10 machine and Matplotlib will cause Python to crash once I import it by calling `import matplotlib.pyplot`:

[image]

When I execute `conda list` on my shell, this is the value of the matplotlib entry:

```
matplotlib                2.2.2                    py36_1    conda-forge
```

I guess I am not the only one with this critical problem. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix - sharing here. Running the following command solved the problem:

```
conda update qt pyqt
```

Comment: Can you mention the versions of your qt and pyqt packages? I am encountering this too. Happens only when using the python.exe as interpreter, but not when using jupyter.